# arcpy.Rename_management() returning ERROR 999999 and [Errno 13]

Tags: arcpy, arccatalog, error-999999

I have a function where I am trying to rename a geodatabase, both `os.rename` and `arcpy.Rename_management()` work in the Python window but not in the script when run as a tool through ArcCatalog.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PecosFieldTools\ProTools_v1.2\PhaseDeliverables\phase.py", line 562, in <module>
    arcpy.Rename_management(in_data=newGdb, out_data=phaseGdb, data_type="Workspace")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 4528, in Rename
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Rename).

Failed to execute (Phase)
```

I think this may be a permission issue but I am admin running this on my own machine. When I wrap in try and except I get these error

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\\\Projects\\\\PhaseMasters\\\\HasData\\\\1810227C\\\\Master\\\\PHASE_DELIVERABLES\\\\DB13635_AF2136641_AP_00_X04.gdb\\\\EQ_AIR_COOLED_EXCHANGER_POLY.LAPTOP-3B9ORV48.16500.16420.sr.lock'")
```

But when I open the file geodatabase I do not see any locks and I am deleting all my cursors. Is there a way to await the locks to be removed with Python?

Here is where I am running the tool from:
[image]

Comment: If you use the Catalog window within ArcMap, then you shouldn't have lock issues, but if you run ArcCatalog and anything else, then there will be conflicts.

Comment: That is what I mean, running the code from the catalog pane of ArcMap the tool fails but the code runs when pasted into the python Window. I turned off the background processing and no change. I don't know enough about what the python script tool does that would cause the code to work in the window but not in a tool?

Comment: I stopped using ArcCatalog when the Catalog window was added to ArcMap, so I wouldn't have lock issues. It doesn't seem counter-intuitive that you can't change the directory name on a Windows volume while that directory is open in another process.

Comment: I am running the tool from inside arcmap. I am not sure why the directory would be in use by another process so I don't understand.

Comment: If you quit out of arcmap completely, can you rename the fgdb folder successfully?

Comment: yes, and the code works in the python window, I used compact_management but I was hoping not to have to do that after the compact the copy/rename works fine

Answer (score 1):

I used arcpy.Compact_management before copying and renaming the geodatabase, tool now works.

```
copyDict = {filePath1:filePath2,filePath3:filePath4}
for k,v in copyDict.iteritems():
    arcpy.Compact_management(k)
    shutil.copytree(k,v)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Copy Success")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you accept this answer

Comment: If I remember correctly this ended up being a big issue with I think it was ArcGIS Pro 1.4, ESRI gave us bug fix release and then wrapped the fix into 1.5, this is the memory I have but it was about 5 years ago. Thanks for your contribution.